# iTunes Connect Product Type identifier 3f

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, units-of-measurement

iTunes connect the sales and trends report has multi product type identifiers, I want to ask about 3F which is defined as Redownload, does this mean that all units shown along with this id are re-installs(re-downloads) to the app? Or is this the total aggregated number? Because numbers are too high (for daily report) compared to the analytical tool, also the same question for the updates?